# Externalize the XSLT code in a springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, xslt, microservices

I want to develop a JSON-REST based Spring-boot service which will consume a XSLT for mapping.
Is there anyway the XSLT can be made configurable, similar to Application Properties file.
That will allow a way of decoupling the service and XSLT logic.

Please suggest, if some way available.

Comment: Do you have some example code that you already made as a starting point?

Comment: its a simple REST service with json request-response